# Save variable from awk to use it in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I would like to run python script for all files in the directory using a `bash` loop. This script is run as

```
python2 script.py $file 1 5 a "f$file" n;
```

`$file` is input file, 1 and 5 are numbers that are the same for all files, `a` should be the first field in the second row of the `$file` (I tried to save the value from `awk` to variable but it is wrong), then output file - the name should be like the input with `f` added to the front -, and then the literal string `n`. I tried:

```
for file in *.b; do
a = awk 'NR==2{print $1}' file
python2 script.py $file 1 5 a "f$file" n; 
done
```

but `a` is wrong.

Comment: "but a is wrong." is not something people can start working / analysing / debugging upon. Get rid of the spaces around the `=` sign, and use "command substitution" like `$(awk ... )`.

Comment: If you are new to bash scripting, I would recommend using [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) (also available as software package in many Linux distributions) so you can avoid syntax errors. In your case, e.g. the variable assignment to `a` is wrong: There must be no spaces (i.e. it must be `a=<something>`), and in order to assign it the result of an external command, you must use "command substitution", i.e. `a="$(awk 'NR==2{print $1}' "$file")"` (notice also it must be `$file`, not just `file`, here).

Comment: Thank you. Now there is a problem with python command. How to find out what `python2 fazuj.py $file 1 5 a "f$file" n` means in each cycle? Maybe, a is string instead of float. Is there an appropriate function for it? I cannot find it.

Comment: What do you mean by "what < ... > means in each cycle"? Do you want to output the result for each loop iteration? The shell doesn't have typed variables, so from the `bash` point of view, everything is a string. I'm afraid you will need to explain further where the problem is ...

Comment: How to use a as float, please?

Comment: If you are now asking how to change the python script to accept a float instead of a string (or vice versa), this is a new question, and you should post it as a new question (but possibly on stackoverflow.com, not here, as it would be off-topic). It not, you have to explain what you want to accomplish in more detail.

Comment: I mean how to convert to float a in this line `python2 fazuj.py $file 1 5.732436 a "f$file" n`. A is now string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105487/discussion-between-alex-and-adminbee).